# Applescript System Preferences automation

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

I'm working on automating setting system preferences, but I have a problem. This code should select Wi-Fi tab but scroll area 1 does not exist unless I click any element that belongs to scroll area manually. I tried emulating click with many external programs but even then I can't access scroll area

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
end tell
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Preferences"
    delay 1

    tell scroll area 1 of window 1
        select row 3 of outline 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Is there any other way to change Dock & Menu Bar settings or just to access scroll area items?

Edit: The end goal is to hide Wi-Fi icon from menu bar.

Comment: What are you actually trying to set? Have you considered `defaults write` instead?

Comment: I'm trying to hide Wi-Fi icon from menu bar.

Comment: Ah, that one's not so easy because it's an array - see https://superuser.com/questions/398071/how-can-i-hide-show-the-wi-fi-menu-item-from-the-terminal-in-os-x/1187870 You could do it in a GUI script though - https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=205986

Comment: Please include your OS version as System Preferences change routinely.

Comment: @Tetsujin, The links your provide in your comment are not really relevant to **macOS Big Sur** as things have changed, and the OP is running **macOS Big Sur**.

Comment: @Mockman, Based on what was said in the OP, they are using **macOS Big Sur**.

Comment: @user3439894 - sorry, my hands-on experience with Big Sur is almost nil.

Comment: @Tetsujin, RE: "sorry, my hands-on experience with Big Sur is almost nil" --  Understandable, and I just wanted you to know. -- The issue the OP is having is due to the changes **Apple** has made in **macOS Big Sur** compared to previous version of **macOS** and I mention that in my answer and why _kludgy_ **UI Scripting** needs to be used in this use case. Even writing directly, e.g. `defaults write com.apple.controlcenter "NSStatusItem Visible WiFi" -bool false` requires a reboot, as I've not found killing any particular _process_ to force it to use the new _value_ works.

Comment: @user3439894 Stating it explicitly would be beneficial to everyone. People who don't use that OS version can respond accordingly and not waste their time. As this is the OP's first question, it is an opportunity to develop good practices.

Comment: @Mockman,RE: "Stating it explicitly would be beneficial to everyone." --  Frankly IMO it should have been made a policy long ago that all questions must contain the version of *macOS** and the explicit **Apple** computer and or other relevant hardware being used, and if not included the question should just outright be deleted! Well maybe not deleted but automatically closed until the information is provided. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The end goal is to hide Wi-Fi icon from menu bar.

**UI Scripting** of **System Preferences** in **macOS Big Sur** has become a nightmare, as many of the methods that used to work in previous versions of **macOS** just no longer do in **macOS Big Sur**. Many **UI elements** report **Parent does not report element as one of its children** when using **Accessibility Inspector** of **Xcode**, which then make it impossible to communicate with them. Or some *code* may work one time and then not the next. I wrote some *code* that opened to **Wi-Fi** and clicked the **Show in Menu Bar** *checkbox*. It worked a few times and now it doesn't.

The original *code* I wrote which sporadically worked I'll not post, however, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* does consistently work as tested under **macOS Big Sur** 11.4, albeit it is what I consider *kludgy* **UI Scripting**, as it's visible on screen, is prone to failure due to timing issues, or if the *hierarchical* **UI element** *structures* change due to **macOS** updates/upgrades.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown below, was tested in **Script Editor** under **macOS Big Sur** 11.4 with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate setting in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

This *script* requires that the **Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** *checkbox* is checked on the **System Preferences** >  **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** tab, and as coded, the *script* checks its status and toggles the *checkbox*, as necessary, based on its current status.

This *script* also first checks to see if the **Wi-Fi** icon is shown on the **Menu Bar** and if not, then halt execution of the script, as its purpose is to act only if it is shown on the **Menu Bar**.

---

### *Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```
--  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.

set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
    "com.apple.controlcenter.plist"

-- Get the value of 'NSStatusItem Visible WiFi' to determine if the
-- Wi-Fi icon is showing on the Menu Bar, and if it's not, then halt
-- execution of the script, as its purpose is to act only if it is.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        set |Wi-Fi Menu Bar Icon Status| to the value of ¬
            the property list item ¬
                "NSStatusItem Visible WiFi"

if |Wi-Fi Menu Bar Icon Status| is false then return


--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it's actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.

set thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
    the POSIX path of ¬
        (path to preferences from user domain as string) & ¬
    ".GlobalPreferences.plist"

--  # Get the value of AppleKeyboardUIMode to determine if the
--  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
--  # checkbox is checked on the System Preferences >  
--  # Keyboard > Shortcuts tab.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell the property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        set keyboardNavigation to the value of ¬
            the property list item "AppleKeyboardUIMode"

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Check the checkbox.
    my toggleKeyboardNavagition()
end if

--  # Open System Preferences to the Dock & Menu Bar pane.
--  # 
--  # This UI Script needs it to be visible, hence the activate command.

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal pane id "com.apple.preference.dock"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    set i to 0
    repeat until exists window "Dock & Menu Bar" of ¬
        application process "System Preferences"
        delay 0.1
        set i to i + 1
        if i ≥ 30 then return
    end repeat
end tell

--  # Tab to the 'Show in Menu Bar' checkbox and uncheck it.

tell application "System Events"
    key code 48 -- # tab key
    delay 0.2
    key code 125 -- # down arrow key
    delay 0.2
    key code 48 -- # tab key
    delay 0.2
    key code 49 -- # spacebar
    delay 0.1
end tell

if keyboardNavigation = 0 then
    --  # Uncheck the checkbox if it
    --  # was previously unchecked.
    my toggleKeyboardNavagition()
end if

delay 0.2

tell application "System Preferences" to quit


--  # Handler(s) #


--  # Toggles checkbox: 'Use keyboard navigation 
--  # to move focus between controls'

on toggleKeyboardNavagition()
    tell application "System Preferences"
        activate
        reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of ¬
            pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        tell front window of ¬
            application process "System Preferences"
            set i to 0
            repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of tab group 1)
                delay 0.1
                set i to i + 1
                if i ≥ 30 then return
            end repeat
            click checkbox 1 of tab group 1
        end tell
    end tell
end toggleKeyboardNavagition
```

---

**Notes:**

If the normal state of the **Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls** *checkbox* is unchecked, then do not run the *script* immediately back to back as it takes a second or two for the *value* of the `property list item "AppleKeyboardUIMode"` in the **users** *global preferences file* to update the change. I'm mentioning this mainly for when doing testing more so than when in normal production use, as it shouldn't be an issue then.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>